# Unity Engine Softbody mesh working weird when attached to chain (using obi rope and obi sofbody)

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, mesh

I am using unity 2021.3.1f1 on Windows 10, the assets used are ObiRope and ObiSoftbody. I am trying to use obi softbody and obi ropes together but the mesh is getting weird.

Basically I have a chain attached to a stand gameObjet and a punchingBag gameObject, this setup working fine but whenever I add softbody component to the punchingBag it either starts moving on it's own weirdly or it becomes a puddle of mesh and fals into the ground.

Here is a drive folder with inspector screenshots, a video showing the problem in play mode: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oEXBowJHwUjxucTng9dBU78w6BB44gwV/view?usp=sharing

I've also attached screenshots bellow. If you need more info let me know. Thank you in advance.

[image: Obi Resolver Inspector]
[image: Bag Inspector]

Edit: So I've enabled Shape Matching on the Obi Solver component (image attached bellow) and it solved the puddle of mesh, but the bag still spins uncontrollable on itself like if something was pulling the chain around.

[Obi Solver Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbn3B.png)

Here is a video exampling it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P5cWqjA...sp=sharing